# Создание сетки для перемещения объектов Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Необходимо создать какое-то view(сетку,таблицу) размерностью 8 на 8 в полную ширину экрана устройства. При клике по этой view, два объекта(drawable) должны совершить движение в соседнюю свободную клетку и если они встретятся, то один уничтожает другой.
**Подскажите пожалуйста:**
1) Какое выбрать view для перемещения по ней объектов при клике?
2) Какой алгоритм нужно применить для того, чтобы когда кликаешь по view, то второй объект искал первый, и с каждым кликом двигался к нему?

*Если есть пример решения подобной задачи или просто советы по реализации, буду очень благодарен.*
Реализовывать буду для Android платформы, на Java или Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

1) tablelayout
2) инициализировать x и y координаты объектов. Встретятся они в координатах (x2;y2)-(x1;y1). И какой-то объект должен будет зайти в клетку другого.

Answer (score 1):

1)Вот тут код игры крестики нолики . Изучив его вы поймете как создавать клетку.Как перемещать клетки и как создавать движок 
[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/games/tictactoe.php)